# How to Create Workers Dynamically in Ballerina

Tags: concurrency, worker, ballerina

How can I create workers dynamically and then wait for them to complete? The number of workers to create is determined at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot dynamically create workers. But by using async calls, the functionality can be achieved. Check this example:

```ballerina
function doSomething() returns int {
    return 1;
}

public function main() {
    future<int>[] results = [];
    int workerLimit = 10;
    foreach int i in 0 ..< workerLimit {
        future<int> asyncResult = start doSomething();
        results.push(asyncResult);
    }

    foreach int i in 0 ..< workerLimit {
        int result = check wait results[I];
        // process result
    }
}
```